# jquery: create/read .css styles at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

I have an application where I'm using [jQuery + maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/)
, and in addition to the highlighting of image map segments, I would like to highlight certain HTML elements dynamically, based on mouseover/mouseout events for the image maps.

I know how to do all of it (just the appropriate calls to addClass and removeClass for the HTML element that I want to highlight) except for one thing. I want to do either of the following:

- create a CSS style at runtime that mirrors the maphilight visual settings (line/fill style + opacity)
- set the maphilight plugin to mirror a CSS style that I have set up.

I'd prefer to do the latter and configure it in a .css file, but at present I don't know how do to either.

Can anyone help me?

---

edit: I'm looking for an answer that includes how to read or write styles from the jQuery maphilight plugin, since it doesn't have much documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It may only change header style sheets. This technique is superior when used correctly. It should never replace a proper class assignment.

```
var renderDropArea = function(renderMe) {
  var dropSheet = document.getElementById('dropAllowedDisplay');
  if (renderMe) {
    // IE 7 & 8
    if (dropSheet.styleSheet) {
      dropSheet.styleSheet.addRule('.dropAllowedHead','background-color:#72F193;');
      dropSheet.styleSheet.addRule('.dropAllowed','background-color:#72F193;');
    } else {
      document.getElementById('dropAllowedDisplay').innerHTML =
        ".dropAllowedHead { background-color:#72F193; } .dropAllowed { background-color:#72F193; }";
    }
  } else {
    // IE 7 & 8
    if (dropSheet.styleSheet) {
      if (dropSheet.styleSheet.rules.length) {
        dropSheet.styleSheet.removeRule(0);
        dropSheet.styleSheet.removeRule(0);
          }
    } else {
      document.getElementById('dropAllowedDisplay').innerHTML = '';
    }   
      }
}
```

Comment: that's helpful for me to understand the underlying CSS DOM manipulations that have to occur, but I'm more interested in how to do this with jQuery, since the justification for using the library is supposed to be to add browser-independence and make it easier to use.

Comment: I do not believe there are any implementations that handle this for you automatically. You could always take this code of mine and put it into a jQuery widget. That is the true power of jQuery. All of the "browser-independence" stems from community contribution. Here is one such contribution http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-creating-stylesheets-in-jquery